# Coerce LuaTeX into outputting a newline character

Tags: luatex, white-space, directlua

I encounter a problem when I wish to output a text file
using a `\directlua` directive. There where I wish a
newline character to be, I run into TeX problems.
My solution is to invoke the `dofile` function to grab a
string called `myNLChar` from an external Lua script.
This string can be written to an output file, and it will
be a true newline character.

File `wrnl2of.lua`:

```
myNLChar = "\n"
```

File `wrnl2of.tex`:

```
This Lua\TeX\ document does not typeset anything
interesting. It outputs a three-line text file
which contains newline characters.\par
\directlua0{
  local myOutFile   = "\jobname.txt"
  local myLuaScript = "\jobname.lua"
  dofile (myLuaScript)
  derDateiname = io.open (myOutFile, "w")
  derDateiname:write ("Alaska"     .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:write ("California" .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:write ("Nebraska"   .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:close ()
}
```

Although this strategy functions well, I suspect that
there are several more elegant solutions to the problem.
I am eager to hear some suggestions.

Comment: I guess one method would be to externalise the entire Lua block to `wrnl2of.lua` and only `dofile` that script in `\directlua`. (Modulo some handling of `\jobname` ...)

Comment: Why don't you use simply `myNLChar="\string\n"` in the directlua? (Or `"Alaska\string\n"`.

Comment: `.. "\string\n"` would also work, see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/luacode/luacode.pdf, p. 2. But I think at a certain point it makes sense to use the `.lua` script approach. (*edit* I see Ulrike was quicker than me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use `\string` here for a simple case

```
This Lua\TeX\ document does not typeset anything
interesting. It outputs a three-line text file
which contains newline characters.\par
\directlua{
  local myOutFile   = "\jobname.txt"
  local myNLChar = "\string\n"
  derDateiname = io.open (myOutFile, "w")
  derDateiname:write ("Alaska"     .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:write ("California" .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:write ("Nebraska"   .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:close ()
}
\bye
```

You could also change the `\catcode` of backslash:

```
This Lua\TeX\ document does not typeset anything
interesting. It outputs a three-line text file
which contains newline characters.\par
\begingroup
\long\def\firstofone#1{#1}
\catcode`\/=0 %
\catcode`/\=12 %
/firstofone{%
/endgroup
/directlua{
  local myOutFile   = "/jobname.txt"
  local myNLChar = "\n"
  derDateiname = io.open (myOutFile, "w")
  derDateiname:write ("Alaska"     .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:write ("California" .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:write ("Nebraska"   .. myNLChar)
  derDateiname:close ()
}%
}
\bye
```

For any Lua code of any length, it's always going to be best to `dofile()` or `require()` it. That might look for example like

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.lua}
function derDateiname(myOutFile)
  local derDateiname = io.open(myOutFile, "w")
  derDateiname:write("Alaska"     .. "\n")
  derDateiname:write("California" .. "\n")
  derDateiname:write("Nebraska"   .. "\n")
  derDateiname:close()
end
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This Lua\TeX\ document does not typeset anything
interesting. It outputs a three-line text file
which contains newline characters.\par
\directlua{
  require("\jobname.lua")
  derDateiname("\jobname")
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd just been editing my post when the comments appeared on the question: I've made CW to avoid any 'rep farming.'

Comment: Imho someone who makes the effort and takes the time to write up a so detailed answer deserves also the reputation - it doesn't matter to me if parts of your answer are in the comments and if you saw or didn't saw them before posting. (And I would never suspect you of rep farming anyway).